# How do I get a list of checkboxes for the item addition form?

Tags: craft3

I know how to get a list of selected checkboxes for a entry:

```
{% for option in entry.myFieldHandle.options %}
  Label: {{ option.label }}
  Value: {{ option }} or {{ option.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

But I can't figure out how to simply display a list of available checkboxes of a certain field in the template. This may be needed if I want, for example, to create a form for adding a entry. Is there such a construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the options independent of any specific entry, you can use the [fields service](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-services-fields.html) to get the field and retrieve its options.

```twig
{% set field = craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle('myFieldHandle') %}
{% for option in field.options %}`
```

In this case, `option` will be an array with the keys `value`, `label` and `default` (this will be `'1'` if the option is the default, or an empty string).